# Ros Indigo cv_bridge OpenCv 2.4.8 source install

Tags: cv-bridge, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I've recently installed Ros Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04. I was having issues with OpenCv installed by sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev as it did not contain the nonfree/* (SIFT SURF and other 2d features) modules.

I decided to uninstall libopencv-dev and install OpenCv 2.4.8 from source. This went just fine; however, several ros packages (cv_bridge being one of them) were uninstalled as they depended on libopencv-dev.

This is the list of all of the ros packages that depend on libopencv-dev

```
  libopencv-dev ros-indigo-camera-calibration
  ros-indigo-compressed-depth-image-transport
  ros-indigo-compressed-image-transport ros-indigo-cv-bridge
  ros-indigo-depth-image-proc ros-indigo-desktop ros-indigo-gazebo-plugins
  ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-indigo-image-geometry
  ros-indigo-image-pipeline ros-indigo-image-proc ros-indigo-image-rotate
  ros-indigo-image-transport-plugins ros-indigo-image-view
  ros-indigo-librviz-tutorial ros-indigo-perception
  ros-indigo-rqt-common-plugins ros-indigo-rqt-image-view
  ros-indigo-rqt-robot-plugins ros-indigo-rqt-rviz ros-indigo-rviz
  ros-indigo-rviz-plugin-tutorials ros-indigo-rviz-python-tutorial
  ros-indigo-simulators ros-indigo-stereo-image-proc
  ros-indigo-theora-image-transport ros-indigo-vision-opencv
  ros-indigo-visualization-tutorials ros-indigo-viz
```

Is there a method to install these packages and force them to depend on my source installed opencv?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186334/ros-indigo-cv_bridge-opencv-2.4.8-source-install/) by [Charlie Murphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18937/charlie-murphy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2014-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, The answer to this question is to uninstall the apt-get installed ros indigo and to install from source. There might be an easier/better way but this worked for me.

After installing from source I just needed to make sure my $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH pointed to the right directories.

---

Originally posted by [Charlie Murphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18937/charlie-murphy/) with karma: 76 on 2014-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-09-26**:
If you want things to depend on packages from source, you must compile them from source too. There's not shortcuts.